# Write an appointment to iOS Calendar from the browser

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, calendar

I'm aware of Google calendar API. I would like to know if there is something similare for iOS, that works without having to install google calendar, google account or being native.

My need is to write on mobile calendar, an appointment scheduled from a web page in React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an [.iCal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)-file on the fly and open it. That enables the user to add it to their calendar.

Comment: It looks like that ics Files don’t open on iOS with chrome

Comment: You said native, that does not imply you want it to work on a 3rd-party app like Chrome. This depends on what Google/3rd-party developers enable in their apps. Safari does allow this though.

Comment: From the Browser not native. It's a good idea to create an ics file, it works perfectly on safari, but I wonder if there is a work around with chrome on iOS

Comment: There's more browsers out there aside from Chrome for iOS. If they decide to not support this you're going to create a whole bunch of workarounds :-(

Comment: @Pietro use the webcal:// protocol for Chrome in iOS like addevent.com does